# jquery strange reg validation problem

Tags: jquery, regex, email

i am doing jquery form validation, then i searched online for some answers like validating email, but strangely none of the regex is working, basically i put my code below in the dom ready

```
function validate_email(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
if (validate_email('gg') {
    alert('papa')
) else {
    alert('mama');
}
```

it is not working on my firefox and ie, please help, if you spotted a problem, thanks

Comment: Install and use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), so you get notified of basic syntax errors. Or use something like Chrome, Safari, or Opera, or recent versions of IE, **all** of which have built-in tools to help you. (Actually, even old versions of IE will notify you of script syntax errors. I expect Firefox does too, but it's been so long since I used it without Firebug...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing your code for formatting, I noticed a missing bracket on this line:

```
if (validate_email('gg') {
```

And an incorrect brace on this one:

```
) else {
```

Since you mentioned firefox, if you haven't got it already, go download [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). This error could have been easily spotted by checking for errors in the firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(validate_email('gg')
```

you've missed the closing ")" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (validate_email('gg')) {
```

You missed a closing bracket in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

PS: I've never seen such a long Regexp for email validation :-)